# Bootstrap navbar collapse button dissapears when on phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

i am designing a website for myself.

The problem that i am having is that when i test my website(not close to being done) on my phone, i can not use the navbar collapse button. it just dissapears.

If anyone can help me i would really appriciate it.

Demo of my broken navbar: http://darrovl.nl/

Code of my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" width="27"> </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <div class="slide-right" data-plugin-options='{"speed":1000, "distance":350}'>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Reviewed your site and reviewed the mobile version. Everything rendered and worked as expected. I could not replicate the issue you are encountering. What type of mobile phone are you using? Are you using any type of emulation software?

Comment: @jameswassinger Yes this is correct, i fixxed it already. thanks for taking a look at it tho.